# UIwebview loading time

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am developing an app that loading data from a URL. The URL for the website is used by html5,so that users can view with mobile view. Now I have a problem that each page consist of text and picture, so the loading time is to long! I would like to adjust to load text first,then load pic. But I am not sure how to do , does someone give me some suggestion?

thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the way, a website gets loaded. But you could try to load the HTML-Code using an `NSURLRequest` and then putting that code into the Webview using `loadHTMLString:`.

But anyway HTML works in that way, that text is displayed first and any images are loaded in following server request.

If your problem is, that the view doesn't show up, before the website is loaded, try to start the loading in `viewDidAppear:` instead of doing it before (eg. while initializing the view)

Comment: Thanks for your advice!
I would use viweDidappear to load the background before the whole data loaded. However, I haven't used it before, so I have no idea.

Comment: Is this a followup question? Then I dont understand. ;) please ask again.